# Child View items are not refreshing

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-checkbox

Here's a code for expandable listview in which each grouo has a checkbox and a textview. There's a Select All checkbox, on click it should change the states of all the child view's checkboxes but its not happening.
Can someone explain why??

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

     ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
        ExpandableListView expListView;
        List<String> listDataHeader;
        static CheckBox selectAll;
        HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // get the listview
            expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
            selectAll=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            // preparing list data
            prepareListData();

            listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

            // setting list adapter
            expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            selectAll.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        /*
         * Preparing the list data
         */
        private void prepareListData() {
            listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
            listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

            // Adding child data
            listDataHeader.add("Top 250");
            listDataHeader.add("Now Showing");
            listDataHeader.add("Coming Soon..");

            // Adding child data
            List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
            top250.add("The Shawshank Redemption");
            top250.add("The Godfather");

            List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
            nowShowing.add("The Conjuring");
            nowShowing.add("Despicable Me 2");


            List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
            comingSoon.add("2 Guns");
            comingSoon.add("The Smurfs 2");


            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            CheckBox cb=(CheckBox)listAdapter.getChildView(0, 0, false, null,         null).findViewById(R.id.cb_child);
            cb.setChecked(true);
            ((BaseExpandableListAdapter) listAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

}
```

**ExpandableListAdapter.java**

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter  {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;


    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
            HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;

    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_layout, null);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_layout, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }   

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.expandablelisttest.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <ExpandableListView
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

    </ExpandableListView>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:text="Select All" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**child_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb_child"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="CheckBox" 
        android:checked="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**group_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method getChildView(..) is used by adapter to populate the expandable child view under group.

I can encourage you to create your own ExpandableListAdapter which extends from BaseExpandableListAdapter (If you have 1 group = 1 item, you can simply use only 1 arrayList with your own POJO object model)

And finnaly, for a full explanation, when you call notifyDataSetChanged(), the list refresh view with the Adapter's data (example get each boolean and use there value for check or uncheck checkbox)

Comment: my question is can I can modify the child view's object in the onClick method but the changes are not reflected.

Comment: If you say my view change are not reflected to my data, it's normal because you modify the view not the data.
To simplify, an Adapter is transform data to view, when you call notifyDataSetChanged() it's get data (local to adapter) and populate view not the inverse.
If you want perform this create your own adapter (simple et more efficient method) but if you want keep your code you need to perform link between checkBox view (set a listener) and your data (but i'm not sure for this method).

Comment: In your getChild() ; CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb_child); and use CheckBox to set check or not this is in a condition like "if(checkAll)" checkAll is an attribut wich is set by a setter (call in your activity) and then call notifyDataSetChanged() and enjoy ;)

Comment: my problem is I don't want to update checkbox in the getChildView() because in android L due to checkbox animation it is showing a delay effect, so I'm trying to update Checkbox prior to calling getChildView() method.

Comment: one solution is: if I create an array of checkboxes that stores the object of all checkboxes in the child view and then I change their state onClick, my task is accomplished. But that;s not a good approach as it creates lots of objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it this way because your ExpandableListAdapter only knows the items strings and not the checkbox.
You have to modify your ExpandableListAdapter to have access to the checkbox in it.
This might help you ---> http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/01/android-expandablelistview-baseexpandablelistadapter.html.
You need to create a structure that contains the objects you want in each items of your list.

Comment: didn't get u...Its like when I'm printing the state of the checkbox using Log.e("State",""+cb_child.isChecked()); I'm getting the right logs i.e. their state is toggling with Select All but not showing.